# Centering SVG clipping path with CSS

Tags: css, svg

I'm blown if I can find a solution to this! Want to center the SVG clip in the surrounding div, as per this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ztfdv9qh/ - Please see link as SVG is long!

```
<div class="svg-wrapper">
    <div class="svg-clipped"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: SVG clipping paths that use absolute coordinates (ie. `clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`) are tricky to work with.  If your clipping path was created using `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` instead, you would have a much easier time of it.  Unfortunately with such a complicated path, doing a conversion will be a pain.  Can you tell us what you are actually trying to achieve and perhaps we suggest the best approach to use.  For instance, what are you actually wanting to clip with the clipPath?

Comment: I need to clip a background <div>, which I can change the colour of dynamically, so it can't have an <img> background, which seems like how most people get round the issue. The logo needs to clips a <div> that is centred in a page like this logo that is currently a .png: http://hono-lulu.ch/

Comment: So the thing you are clipping is just a single colour `<div>`?  If that's the case, you don't need to use a clipping path.

Comment: How about in the instance that the web page had an image and I needed a transparent clip round the <div> what could I use in that case?

Comment: SVGs have transparent backgrounds. So all you need to do is use a regular `<path>` instead of a clip.  http://jsfiddle.net/ztfdv9qh/3/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ztfdv9qh/4/

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so I've spent way more time playing with this than I wanted to and, unfortunately, I still feel the need to preface my "answer" with this message: I hope someone else has a better answer for you.

With that said, I could find possible choices:

1. Use the `transform: translate(x,y)` to force the clippath into the center. This likely isn't what you want since it would require a fixed width space.
2. Set `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` on the `<clippath>`. This changes the coordinate system to be relative to the bounding box of the element to which the clipping path applies to. It also gets the same width and height of this bounding box. This sounded great until I found the big "but": The coordinates for the points used in your `<path>` need to written as values within a range of [0,1]. This means that you will need to rewrite the `<path>` element. Here is a [reference](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/#clippathunits) for a better explanation of this option.

Good Luck!

Comment: Same article I started with. I like your idea though, thanks for drawing my attention to it! I need to experiment some more.

Answer (score 0):

change your .svg-clipped to this:

```
.svg-clipped {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
  clip-path: url(#svgPath);
  background: #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

and put`<center>` in the first before `<div class="svg-wrapper">` and put `</center>` after `</svg>` at the end of code !
And also remove `.svg-wrapper` class in your style !

Comment: Sorry man, doesn't work for me. Did you get it working in the Fiddle?